# Looks like </b> does not turn off bold text in generic html

Tags: html

I have the following code being generated in a c# asp.net mvc application:

```
 <div class="col-5">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-9">
             <div class="card">
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">You are currently saving a total of <b>15%</b> of your paycheck</h5>
                     <hr />
                     <p class="card-text" style="font-size: smaller">
                         <b>Pre-tax</b><br /><b>9.00%</b> per paycheck<br />Est. <b>$93.75 bi-monthly
                     </p>
                     <hr />
                     <p class="card-text" style="font-size: smaller">
                         <b>Roth</b><br /><b>6.00%</b> per paycheck<br />Est. <b>$62.50 bi-monthly
                     </p>
                     <hr />
                     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" id="submitButton">Review and Submit</button>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I have no custom css files and I am making use of all generic bootstrap css files.

This is what it looks like when the page is generated:

[image]

In the card on the right, the Pre-Tax literal, the percent, and the dollar amount and literal are bold.  The text "per paycheck" and the text "Est." are not.  But it looks like the entire section for "Roth" is all bold.  Any suggestions as to why this is happening?  I am trying to get the bolding for the "Roth" section to be the same as the "Pre-tax" section.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: use multiple spans inside paragraph tag

Comment: You have some missing close bold tags, ie after $93 and $62 text

Comment: @Phix - Yes, I saw that after I posted.  But that doesn't explain why the words "per paycheck" in the Roth section is displaying as bold.

Comment: @Phix - It just fixed itself.  I cleared my browsing data and its appearing the way I wanted.  Sorry to waste your time.